# Accessing parsim data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, simulink

Good evening, May I please get advice with the following Matlab code? Here it is:

```
%% CLEAR ALL
close all
clear all
clc
%% LOAD MODEL AND LHC FILE
tic %start the clock
idx=1;
model = 'PG_PN_basic_rev1'; %This is the simulink file you wish to run.
load_system(model);
load 'LHC_input.mat' %Call in the file created by LHC_Final.m
LHC = (LHC1_input);
k_dc = LHC((1:5),1);
k_r = LHC((1:5),2);
a_1 = LHC((1:5),3);
b_1 = LHC((1:5),4);
Kg_PG = LHC((1:5),5);
Kg_PN = LHC((1:5),6);

for i = length(k_dc):-1:1
in(i) = Simulink.SimulationInput('PG_PN_basic_rev1');
in(i) = in(i).setVariable('k_dc',k_dc(i));

    for j = length(k_r):-1:1
    in(j) = in(j).setVariable('k_r',k_r(j));

        for k = length(a_1):-1:1
        in(k) = in(k).setVariable('a_1',a_1(k));

            for l = length(b_1):-1:1  
            in(l) = in(l).setVariable('b_1',b_1(l));
    
                for m = length(Kg_PG):-1:1
                in(m) = in(m).setVariable('Kg_PG',Kg_PG(m));

                    for n = length(Kg_PN):-1:1
                    in(n) = in(n).setVariable('Kg_PN',Kg_PN(n));
            
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
out = parsim(in, 'ShowProgress', 'on');
% eval(['PN_batch', int2str(idx),' =PN;']);
% data = eval(['PN_batch', int2str(idx)]);
% a{idx} = data;
% idx=idx+1;
% run = idx
timeElapsed = toc %How long did you code run for?
```

I wish to be able to generate an output file per parsim run (PN_batch1, PN_batch2,...etc.). However, the data often falls under just 1 output, and isn't divided up into readable workspace objects that I can read later with another script. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`out` is a vector of length equal to the number of simulations with the data of a simulation stored in each entry. If you have *to workspace* blocks in your model, you can access that data per simulation using `out(10).NameOftoWorkspaceData`, in case you want to get the data of the 10th simulation. More info on the `out` variable can be found [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/simulink.simulationoutput-class.html) on the Mathworks site.

Tip: run the model and check out the variable `out`, then you can explore its structure